# How to create sources.list.d directory in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have deleted sources.list.d directory from `/etc/apt/` on my  ubuntu 16.04 system.
Now, I dont know how to get that directory.

Answer (score 1):

By default that directory is empty, and if you did had any files in there but deleted the directory permanently (with `rm -rf` for example) you can't easily recover the files anyway so it's just a matter of creating the directory again like @karel mentioned in the comment above:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```